# Error while deploying HTML5 app with Ubuntu SDK

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-sdk, html5

I got this error message while deploying a HTML5 app with UbuntuSDK. Can anyone help me?

```
:-1: warning: desktop_Exec (vp99): found unexpected Exec with architecture 'all': ./qtc_device_debughelper.py

:-1: warning: security_policy_groups_safe_vp99 (debug): (REJECT) reserved policy group 'debug': not for production use
The debug policy group is automatically injected and should only be used for development.
To create a package for the store use the publish tab!
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this error performing "Publish -> Validate existing Click package" in the Ubuntu SDK.

Performing "Publish -> Create and Validate Click package" solved it for me.